# How setting state in React component using React-Router and RouteComponentProps (TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, state

I am educating myself in React and React-Router and want to do a very small login page where the user can login to the secret page. I am using TypeScript.

I have done a running example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mirzakhani-j1sdc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am not sure if I have declared the `PropsType` correct to apply it on the `Login` component. And when using `RouteComponentProps` as properties I do not seem to have access to the state of the component so i can set `isAuthenticated=true`.

So my question is how I can update the state so `isAuthenticated` gets the new value of true? Because `this.state.isAuthenticated` is not accessible from the Login component, but `this.props.isAuthenticated` is!

Do I have to map the state to the props to get the updated state or what exactly do I need to get this as I want?

To summarize the code I have in the example above:

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Layout } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Layout />, rootElement);
```

App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Login } from "./loginpage";
import { SecretPage } from "./secretpage";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export class Layout extends Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login
              history={null}
              location={null}
              match={null}
              isAuthenticated={false}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Redirect to="/login" />;
          </Route>
          <Route path="/secret">
            <SecretPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

loginpage.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Component, MouseEvent } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

interface State {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
}

type PropsType = RouteComponentProps<any> & {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  history: any;
  location: any;
  match: any;
};

export class Login extends Component<PropsType> {
  constructor(props: PropsType, context?: any) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { isAuthenticated: false };
  }

  private login(e?: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    console.log("Logging in...");
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
  }

  public render() {
    console.log("Is authenticated: " + this.props.isAuthenticated);
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/secret");
    }

    return (
      <div className="login">
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Log in" onClick={e => this.login(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

secretpage.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

export class SecretPage extends Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="secretPage">
        <h1>Welcome to secret page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried to here? That would make the question simple to understand

Comment: You can create a `PrivateRoute` component and then have it handle redirects. `react-router` has a well explained [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you set `isAuthenticated` to false when you pass that prop down to the `<Login />` component. And then you try to use that state in the `<Login />` component. It would be better if you lift up your state to live in the `<App />` component and then pass it down to `<Login />` via a prop.

It can look like this:
App.tsx

```
this.state = { isAuthenticated: false };

private login(e?: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  console.log("Logging in...");
  this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
}

if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
  this.props.history.push("/secret");
}

<Login
  history={null}
  location={null}
  match={null}
  isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
  login={this.login}
/>
```

And in the  component, instead of running the function you had in there you ran the one that is now instead passed down.

`<input type="button" value="Log in" onClick={() => this.props.login} />`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This is not a (direct) answer to your question. Ignore this if you just need a straight answer.

But I feel creating `Public` & `Private` routes by creating a simple wrapper around route might help solve your problem in an elegant way!

There are so many articles regarding this and I found this on google https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Feel free to find some other easy tutorial if you could.