# How make my login function working with React functional components using React-Router (TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have asked a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993545/how-setting-state-in-react-component-using-react-router-and-routecomponentprops) 
The difference from that question is this question is about to solve the same problem with Reacts functional components, and my other question is how to solve it by React class components with states and `withRouter` (still unanswered).

What I want to achieve is to create a very simple login page. I have read and followed the tutorial at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow but I have tried to do it with my own code, but I cannot get it to work. When pressing the login button I am never passed to the login page. It doesn´t seem the redirect process work.

What am I missing?

app.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import SecretPage from "./secretpage";
import Login from "./loginpage";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Redirect to="/login" />;
        </Route>
        <Route path="/secret">
          <SecretPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

login.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { MouseEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import { useHistory, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import * as H from "history";

function onLogin({
  e,
  setAuthenticated,
  history,
  from,
}: {
  e?: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
  setAuthenticated: (b: boolean) => void;
  history: H.History;
  from: H.Location;
}) {

 authenticate().then(res => {
    if (res) {
      console.log("Logging in -> secretpage, from: " + JSON.stringify(from));
      setAuthenticated(true);
      history.replace(from);
    }
  });
}

function authenticate(): Promise<boolean> {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

export default function Login() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    console.log("Now authenticaed:" + JSON.stringify(location));

    return (
      <Route path="/secret">
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: "/secret",
          state: { from: location }
        }} />
      </Route>
    )

  }

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <br />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Log in to secret page"
        onClick={e => onLogin({ e, setAuthenticated, history, from})}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

secretpage.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function SecretPage() {
  console.log("Rendering secret page");
  return (
    <div className="secretPage">
      <h1>Welcome to secret page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login.tsx `Redirect` is not required to wrap inside a `Route` component. 
You can find in the example you attached at reactraining. you could see `Redirect` is used as `RenderProp`.
Find more about render props [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

And as well, in your `app.tsx` 
change the order of your Route path 
from:

```
<Route path="/">
  <Redirect to="/login" />;
</Route>
<Route path="/secret">
 <SecretPage />
</Route>
```

to:

```
<Route path="/secret">
  <SecretPage />
</Route>
<Route path="/">
  <Redirect to="/login" />
</Route>
```

As you wrapped your code inside `Switch` in `app.tsx`. it will always take the first matched route. in your case, it is always `/`. And it has redirection.
So you are redirected login. when you are routing to `/secret`.